# Powershell to rename excel worksheet on multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to rename the only active worksheet in multiple excel workbooks in the same directory. So for instance I have 4 excel spreadsheets all with different names and different sheet names but I need all the sheet names in the workbooks to have the same name, which in this case is 'Sheet1'. I have found the following code from a similar question asked on here but it does not work:

```
Function RenameTab ($ExcelFileName, $OutLoc){
    $excelFile = "C:\tmp\" + $excelFileName + ".xlsx"
    $xldoc =  New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $xldoc.Visible = $false
    $xldoc.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Worksheets){
        $n = $ExcelFileName + "_" + $worksheet.Name
        $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
        $worksheet.name = "Sheet1"
        $workbook.SaveAs($OutLoc + $n + ".xlsx")
        $workbook.Close()
    }
    $xldoc.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Does it give an error?  If so, please [edit] in the details of the error.  If not, then please provide an example of how you call `RenameTab`, what you expected to happen and what does not work.  From reviewing the code, it looks like it should do what you request, if you change `Sheet1` and adjust the `$ExcelFileName` and `$OutLoc` parameters accordingly.

Comment: 1st when presenting foreign code always state the origin. 2nd you don't tell how you **use** the function. 3rd for a function to be universally usable don't pass just the basename and imply a location like `C:\tmp`.

Comment: As for (rename the only active worksheet in multiple excel workbooks), you have nothing in the post that says how you are defining this. An worksheet is only active when the workbook is opened and in use. Your post is only targeting the first worksheet in the workbook, that does not translate into your use case above.

Comment: There is no error when completed. A bit of background on the code, as I stated in the original post I grabbed this from another post on this forum. I'm a beginner when it comes to Powershell so still unsure how some of the functions work. I was hoping this code would change the name of the worksheet in multiple workbooks in a directory. Each workbook only has 1 worksheet hence the comment about 'rename the only active worksheet in multiple excel workbooks' (Should have explained that better).

Comment: The code below does what I need it to but only on one file, I'm unsure how to make this work with multiple excel files:                                                      
$xlspath = "C:\tmp\test.xlsx"
$xldoc = new-object -comobject Excel.application
$workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($xlspath )
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$worksheet.name = "Sheet1"
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.Close()
$xldoc.Quit()